# Matplotlib why am I getting "ValueError: view limit minimum 0.0 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value"?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, finance

I'm going through a Python for Finance tutorial on YouTube but I'm getting stuck with a Matplotlib error. My code scrapes the names of S&P 500 names from Wikipedia and then uses Pandas data_reader to pull the stock info from Yahoo Finance for each ticker.

The returning dataframe has a date column and columns for each stock ticker name.

All of that seemingly works fine using the `compile_data()` function, but I'm getting `ValueError: view limit minimum 0.0 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value.` after trying to plot the csv dataframe with `visualize_data` using Pandas .plot() for a given symbol (ie AAPL). Date and symbol column have no missing values.

Please help me out!

Full code of tutorial can be found [here](https://pythonprogramming.net/stock-price-correlation-table-python-programming-for-finance/?completed=/combining-stock-prices-into-one-dataframe-python-programming-for-finance/) (pythonprogramming.net).

Here's the code:

```
def compile_data():
    with open('sp500tickers.pickle','rb') as f:
        tickers = pickle.load(f)

    main_df = pd.DataFrame()

    for count, ticker in enumerate(tickers):
        df = pd.read_csv('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker))
        df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

        df.rename(columns={'Adj Close': ticker}, inplace=True)
        df.drop(['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume'], axis=1, inplace=True)

        if main_df.empty: # boolean for if empty or not
            main_df = df
        else:
            main_df = main_df.join(df, how='outer')

        if count % 100 == 0:
            print(count)

    #print(main_df.head())
    main_df.to_csv('sp500_joined_closes.csv')


compile_data()

def visualize_data():
    df = pd.read_csv('sp500_joined_closes.csv')
    df['AAPL'].plot()
    plt.show()

visualize_data()
```

Here's the full Error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_tools.py in _handle_shared_axes(axarr, nplots, naxes, nrows, ncols, sharex, sharey)
    306                 for ax in axarr:
--> 307                     layout[ax.rowNum, ax.colNum] = ax.get_visible()
    308 

IndexError: index 5 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-87-55ac2958f267> in <module>
      4     plt.show()
      5 
----> 6 visualize_data()

<ipython-input-87-55ac2958f267> in visualize_data()
      1 def visualize_data():
      2     df = pd.read_csv('sp500_joined_closes.csv')
----> 3     df['AAPL'].plot(x='Date')
      4     plt.show()
      5 

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py in __call__(self, kind, ax, figsize, use_index, title, grid, legend, style, logx, logy, loglog, xticks, yticks, xlim, ylim, rot, fontsize, colormap, table, yerr, xerr, label, secondary_y, **kwds)
   2740                            colormap=colormap, table=table, yerr=yerr,
   2741                            xerr=xerr, label=label, secondary_y=secondary_y,
-> 2742                            **kwds)
   2743     __call__.__doc__ = plot_series.__doc__
   2744 

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py in plot_series(data, kind, ax, figsize, use_index, title, grid, legend, style, logx, logy, loglog, xticks, yticks, xlim, ylim, rot, fontsize, colormap, table, yerr, xerr, label, secondary_y, **kwds)
   1996                  yerr=yerr, xerr=xerr,
   1997                  label=label, secondary_y=secondary_y,
-> 1998                  **kwds)
   1999 
   2000 

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py in _plot(data, x, y, subplots, ax, kind, **kwds)
   1799         plot_obj = klass(data, subplots=subplots, ax=ax, kind=kind, **kwds)
   1800 
-> 1801     plot_obj.generate()
   1802     plot_obj.draw()
   1803     return plot_obj.result

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py in generate(self)
    252         self._add_table()
    253         self._make_legend()
--> 254         self._adorn_subplots()
    255 
    256         for ax in self.axes:

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py in _adorn_subplots(self)
    429                                 naxes=nrows * ncols, nrows=nrows,
    430                                 ncols=ncols, sharex=self.sharex,
--> 431                                 sharey=self.sharey)
    432 
    433         for ax in self.axes:

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_tools.py in _handle_shared_axes(axarr, nplots, naxes, nrows, ncols, sharex, sharey)
    325                     if sharex or len(ax.get_shared_x_axes()
    326                                      .get_siblings(ax)) > 1:
--> 327                         _remove_labels_from_axis(ax.xaxis)
    328 
    329         if ncols > 1:

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_tools.py in _remove_labels_from_axis(axis)
    278 
    279 def _remove_labels_from_axis(axis):
--> 280     for t in axis.get_majorticklabels():
    281         t.set_visible(False)
    282 

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py in get_majorticklabels(self)
   1251     def get_majorticklabels(self):
   1252         'Return a list of Text instances for the major ticklabels.'
-> 1253         ticks = self.get_major_ticks()
   1254         labels1 = [tick.label1 for tick in ticks if tick.label1.get_visible()]
   1255         labels2 = [tick.label2 for tick in ticks if tick.label2.get_visible()]

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py in get_major_ticks(self, numticks)
   1406         'Get the tick instances; grow as necessary.'
   1407         if numticks is None:
-> 1408             numticks = len(self.get_majorticklocs())
   1409 
   1410         while len(self.majorTicks) < numticks:

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py in get_majorticklocs(self)
   1323     def get_majorticklocs(self):
   1324         """Get the array of major tick locations in data coordinates."""
-> 1325         return self.major.locator()
   1326 
   1327     def get_minorticklocs(self):

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py in __call__(self)
   1432     def __call__(self):
   1433         'Return the locations of the ticks'
-> 1434         self.refresh()
   1435         return self._locator()
   1436 

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py in refresh(self)
   1452     def refresh(self):
   1453         'Refresh internal information based on current limits.'
-> 1454         dmin, dmax = self.viewlim_to_dt()
   1455         self._locator = self.get_locator(dmin, dmax)
   1456 

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py in viewlim_to_dt(self)
   1203                              'often happens if you pass a non-datetime '
   1204                              'value to an axis that has datetime units'
-> 1205                              .format(vmin))
   1206         return num2date(vmin, self.tz), num2date(vmax, self.tz)
   1207 

ValueError: view limit minimum 0.0 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value. This often happens if you pass a non-datetime value to an axis that has datetime units
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my own problem. To view the plots in jupyter notebook, I was using interactive plots with `%matplotlib notebook` instead of `%matplotlib inline`. Switching back to inline fixed the issue.